# java script functionality only in mobile device

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I want java script functionality only in mobile device 767px.
This is my code

```
$('#my-btnn').click(function () {
    $('#mobile-login').hide();
    $('#user-settings').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: You want to hide `#my-btnn` or you want click on it to do nothing?

Comment: i want this javascript function only in mobile device 767px while i want disable this javascript function in desktop site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply check window width in order to determine if function should work or not:

```
$('#my-btnn').click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $('#mobile-login').hide();
        $('#user-settings').slideToggle('fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your click by checking your resolution. Use onResize and check by screen.width

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (screen.width <= 767) {
         $('#my-btnn').bind('click', function () {
            $('#mobile-login').hide();
            $('#user-settings').slideToggle('fast');
         });
    }
});
```

And you can check if you were binded early.

Or you can just to add this checking in onReload

Comment: Note that it will end up in dozens of click event handlers because on each window.onresize event (for small dimensions) there will be new binding.

Comment: its great... just a minor issue with this code that my toggle not staying open onlclick.